# For some time or For a while

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Which one is correct and what is the difference? Are they interchangeable? Should I use "for" with *a while*?

I understand that some time means for a long period of time but I mean about a description a period of time of an unknown length.

> I liked it for ***some time***. For ***some time*** he wanted to be a doctor.
>
> I liked it **for** **a while**. **For** **a while** he wanted to be a doctor.

Comment: There is no meaningful distinction between the two. Both leave the period concerned undefined, whether hours, days, months or years.